# Android: HorizontalScrollView in a ListView row Item, focus issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a **ListView** that each item has a layout that contains a **HorizontalScrollView**.
the problem is that I can't get the whole list item to be focused on when the user clicks or touches a list item.

how can I solve this ?

Thanks

**Edit: the HorizontalScrollView looks like this:**

```
<HorizontalScrollView
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:fadingEdge="none"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView" 
        ></HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK Guys, I got it.
in the **LinearLayout** wrapping my **HorizontalScrollView** I added the following attribute:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

so the **HorizontalScrollView** did not receive focus.

thanks

Comment: Does the scrollable part of your list item is clickable? I have a single scrollable TextView as a list item and the on click is not forwarded to the ListView.

Comment: @ol_v_er: Nope they aren't. I have the same problem here. Have not found a solution for it yet

Comment: One guy of my team built a custom HorizontalScrollView and a custom ListView to handle the Scroll in the HorizontalScrollView and the click via onSingleTapUp. It now works quite fine.

Answer (score 0):

The Layout looks very complex with `HorizontalScrollView` inside a `ListView`. You should simplify  your UI. Use a [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html). I feel it suits your UI requirement right.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the expandable list view will not suit the layout design of my app.

Comment: Then its better to split the screen into two screens. One with `ListView` that shows the preview of each item, on tapping on any item  takes you to the next screen that shows the detailed view with scrolling. Hope that helps.

Comment: Oh I saw your answer after posting my comment.